# How to Make column scrollable with keeping Expanded Widgets flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello everyone I'm trying to convert Column to be scrollable I tried to warp Column in SingleChildScrollView (With removing all Expanded Widgets) but I get an error I converted the column to ListView (With removing all Expanded Widgets) but I get an error.

Is there any solution to keep Expanded Widgets?

So could anyone help me? Please

this is my code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      floatingActionButton: buttonTheme,
      drawer: SideMenu(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: DropdownButton(
              underline: SizedBox(),
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.language,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              items: AppLanguage.languageList()
                  .map<DropdownMenuItem<AppLanguage>>(
                    (lang) => DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: lang,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [Text(lang.flag), Text(lang.name)],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
              onChanged: (AppLanguage language) {
                _changeLanguage(language);
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
        centerTitle: true,
        //automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(
          getTranslation(context, 'main_app_bar'),
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: WeatherWidget(
                  deglaPalmsWeatherData: widget.deglaPalmsWeather,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 20,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 1,
                            child: MapWidget(),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 10,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 1,
                            child: ServicesWidget(),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 20,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 20,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 1,
                            child: InfoWidget(),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 10,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 1,
                            child: BusWidget(),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 20,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: SoonWidget(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              DCCopyRights(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        height: bannerHeight,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: try to wrap your column with `Expanded`

Comment: @FahmiSawalha with using which Widget SingleChildScrollView or ListView ?

Comment: i think you should go with the singleChildScrollView

Comment: @FahmiSawalha not working I get this error `Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a _SingleChildViewport widget.  `

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and it worked fine for me, I used PageView with scrollDirection & pageSnapping

```
PageView(
         scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
         pageSnapping: false,
         children: [Column(),
                    Column()])
```

I had to reflex the widgets to fit all screens but it worked great for me because I added a lot of widgets now it looks like one scrollable column.
I know it's not the best solution but it did what I want.